# MvvmCross BackgroundColor binding

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding, mvvmcross

I'm trying to bind a text backgroundcolor from a label and change it from its ViewModel, but it isn't working for me.

View:

```
       <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Label Text="Number of seats:" Grid.Row="4" FontAttributes="Bold" />
          <Label Text="{Binding SeatsNumber}" Grid.Row="4" BackgroundColor="{Binding SeatsBackgroundColor}"/>
       </StackLayout>
```

ViewModel:

```
public string SeatsBackgroundColor { get; set; }
```

And I setted to "Green" on the constructor, but when the application starts the color didn't change.
Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

Ok, I solved.
The issue was that the stacklayout the I showed was inside a ListView so I had to add a new property (to set the backgroundColor) inside the Model that I was using for fill the list.